# one space remains but more than 1 spaces removed in linux

Tags: linux, awk, replace, command-line, command

I have below values in  my text file:

```
, 2,

,                2,
```

I want to change it as if more than one spaces exits removed the value, but for one space the value remains:

```
, 2,
```

and also the second want removed.
do any one has an idea ? I have below code and this code doesn't consider one space or more than one space.

```
BEGIN{
  RS="^$"
}
{
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+[2]+,/,"")
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+[3]+,/,"")
  $1=$1
}
1
```

Comment: Some info here: `RS="^$"` can most likely be replaced by `RS=""`. This is a special `RS` to signify a sequence of empty lines is considered as a record-separator.

Answer (score 2):

With a simpler awk (note 2 spaces between `/  /`:

```
awk 'NF && !/  /' file
```

or else:

```
awk 'NF && !/[[:blank:]]{2}/' file
```

```
, 2,
```

We are checking one condition which is `NF && !/  /` which means print if it is a non-empty line and double space doesn't exist anywhere in that line.

Comment: Be aware, there are two spaces between `/  /` in the above command.

Comment: Yes there is. May be I should have used `/[[:blank:]]{2}/` to make it more visible

Answer (score 0):

As per shown samples, could you please try following. This will print only those lines which are starting from `,` then 1 space following with 1 or more digits then `,`.

```
awk '/^, [0-9]+,$/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

To not print lines with more than one space, use:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/ /," ")<=1' file
```

Output:

```
, 2,
```

Notice the empty record.

Answer (score 0):

```
# retain lines with exactly one space character
awk -F'[ ]' 'NF==2'

# retain lines with maximum of one space character
awk -F'[ ]' 'NF<=2'
```

**Note** that the input field separator is assigned within character class. Default `FS` is single space which will remove leading/trailing spaces/tabs/newlines and splits based on one or more continuous occurrences of these three characters.

**Edit:** The question isn't very clear on reading it again. Perhaps you want to replace multiple spaces to single space?

```
$ sed -E 's/ +/ /g' ip.txt
, 2,

, 2,
```